# Product of nonzero elements of Z/pZ

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was wondering if someone could guide me regarding the following question: "If p is congruent to 1 modulo 4, we may proceed as follows. Recall that Z/pZ is a field. Let
L = 1 × 2 × · · · × (p − 2) × (p − 1),
viewed as product of all the nonzero elements of Z/pZ. Explain why, as an element of Z/pZ,
L = (−1)^(p−1/2) × (1^2) × (2^2) × · · · × ((p − 1)/2)^2"

I understand that p congruent to 1 mod 4 implies (p-1)/2 is even, and that p-1 is congruent to -1 mod p but I'm not sure how to progress from here. Could someone give me some advice on how to get started? Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Hint:  $i\times (p-i)\equiv -i^2\pmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

The inversion map $\iota:t\mapsto t^{-1}$ defines a permutation of the units group $\Bbb F_p^*$ of the field $$\Bbb F_p:=\frac{\Bbb Z}{p\Bbb Z}=\{\bar0,\bar1,\dots,\overline{p-1}\}$$ Except for the $\iota$ orbit $\{-\bar1\}$, the elements of an $\iota$ orbit together have a product of $\bar1$. $$\therefore\;\prod_{t\in\Bbb F_p^*}t=\prod_{X\in\mathcal O(\iota)}\prod_{t\in X}t=\prod_{t\in\{-\bar1\}}t=-\bar1$$ where the $\Bbb F_p^*$ partition $\mathcal O(\iota)$ is the family of all $\iota$ orbits.